# Pymongo: How to retrieve all rows where the indexes are in a list of values?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

In pymongo, I get retrieve a row by index value using this

`list(mycol.find( { "_id": 5 } ))`

How would I retrieve a list of documents from a list of indices

I attempted this

`list(mycol.find( { "_id": [5,3,4] } ))`

which did not return any results.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
ilist = [5, 3, 6, 31]
ret = mycol.find({ "_id": {"$in" : ilist}})
list(ret)
```